# TypeError: Invalid shape (154, 600, 800) for image data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to plot the data in my files. I tried executing the below code. I was getting the error as

```
TypeError: Invalid shape (154, 600, 800) for image data.
```

```py
import os
import pydicom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Change the working directory to "DICOM FILES"
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/Data')

# Get the list of all DICOM files in the directory
dicom_files = [f for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith('.dcm')]

# Loop over all DICOM files and read them one by one
for file in dicom_files:
    # Read the DICOM file
    ds = pydicom.dcmread(file)

    # Extract and print information from the DICOM metadata
    print(f"Patient Name: {ds.PatientName}")
    print(f"Patient ID: {ds.PatientID}")
    print(f"Study Date: {ds.StudyDate}")
    print(f"Study Description: {ds.StudyDescription}")
    # Extract the pixel data and display the image
    pixel_array = ds.pixel_array
    plt.imshow(pixel_array, cmap='gray') 
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct code to plot the image:

```
pixel_array = ds.pixel_array
plt.imshow(pixel_array[0], cmap='gray') 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you had written:

```py
plt.imshow(pixel_array, cmap="gray")
```

When you should have written:

```py
plt.imshow(pixel_array[0], cmap="gray")
```

You passed in a 3D array rather than a 2D array.

Full code:

```py
import os
import pydicom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Change the working directory to "DICOM FILES"
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/Data')

# Get the list of all DICOM files in the directory
dicom_files = [f for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith('.dcm')]

# Loop over all DICOM files and read them one by one
for file in dicom_files:
    # Read the DICOM file
    ds = pydicom.dcmread(file)

    # Extract and print information from the DICOM metadata
    print(f"Patient Name: {ds.PatientName}")
    print(f"Patient ID: {ds.PatientID}")
    print(f"Study Date: {ds.StudyDate}")
    print(f"Study Description: {ds.StudyDescription}")
    # Extract the pixel data and display the image
    pixel_array = ds.pixel_array
    plt.imshow(pixel_array[0], cmap="gray") 
    plt.show()
```

I hope this helps.